# Create site as disabled model

Tags: 2013, office-365, site

My problem is to create my site as a model because I use several times the same lists with the same columns. BUT, the option to create the site as a model is not showing, print follows below: (It is in Portuguese)

[image]

I have a website reference, but is not showing up this function for me.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-site-templates-60371b0f-00e0-4c49-a844-34759ebdd989?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__save_a_site

Microsoft Web site, but I'm using Office 365 and am finding that this is the reason of my problem.

Note: I'm on a site below the main, eg contoso.sharepoint.com/clients

If've been down this site is certainly not have the functionality but in this case is to have as Sharepoint 2013 installed in the server contains this feature.

Does the problem is Office 365? Algue can give me another solution for this as it takes to create many of the same sites.

Answer (score 1):

The option isn't showing up in Office 365 but you can just add  `/_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx` to the URL of your site to go to the page for saving the site as a template. Depending on the type of site this may not work.

If the purpose it to reuse a single list, then it might be a better option to:

- only save that list as a template (available in list settings).
- create a content type and use that in your lists.

or a combination of these.

Comment: In fact I have several lists, pages, libraries, javascripts, etc ... So if I have to save everything as a model it will take me a LONG time and will not be making a nice way to maintenance. But I appreciate your suggestion :). We are made to share knowledge.